# How does WaitHandle know which threads to signal for WaitOne methods?

Tags: c#, multithreading

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitone(v=vs.110).aspx) says that the "WaitOne" (and similar) methods wait for a signal from a specific WaitHandle.

How does the WaitHandle know how many threads or WaitOne methods are listening to it, so it can signal to them?

Comment: Magic. Or more accurately, there are kernel queues managing this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I'm guessing the "WaitOne" method signals the kernel to queue him up for said WaitHandle?

Comment: Are there any particular use case in mind, that you want to know how many threads are waiting? Or this is just pure curiosity?

Comment: `WaitOne` is a thin wrapper around `WaitForSingleObject` (on Windows, at least), which in turn is a thin user-mode wrapper around what the kernel calls [dispatcher objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/introduction-to-kernel-dispatcher-objects). The exact details for how the kernel manages this are no doubt fascinating; I'll freely admit I don't have all of those either.